# reinterpret_cast integer to pointer with upcast

Tags: c++, casting, c++14, reinterpret-cast

Is the following code safe :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

struct A{
  int i = 0;
  virtual int foo() {return i;}
};
struct B : A{
  int foo() override {return i+2;}
};

using handle_t = std::uintptr_t;
handle_t get(B& a){
  return reinterpret_cast<handle_t>(&a);
}

void use(handle_t h){
  auto p= reinterpret_cast<A*>(h); // 
  std::cout << p->foo() << "\n";
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  B a;
  auto h = get(a);
  use(h);
  return 0;
}
```

[CppReference's page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) says one can :

- reinterpret_cast from B* to std::uintptr_t
- reinterpret_cast from std::uintptr_t to B* (because it's the same type back and forth)
- reinterpret_cast from B* to A*

So, is it safe to merge the last two ?

Comment: I can't see that the cppreference page says you can use `reinterpret_cast` for upcasting, as you claim with "reinterpret_cast from B* to A*". If it does then it's wrong. But I think the error here is yours.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf On the linked page (5) says you can dereference the result of `reinterpret_cast` if it is allowed by type aliasing rule, and below (section Type Aliasing rule), it says that it is allowed if *"AliasedType is a (possibly cv-qualified) base class of DynamicType"* (I do not claim this is conformant with standard wording though).

Comment: Link is fixed. The upcasting is allowed by rule 5 (6 seems to work too though) with T1=B* and T2=A* and the type aliasing rules below. Casting from DynamicType to AliasedType if  AliasedType is a (possibly cv-qualified) base class of DynamicType

Comment: @Davidbrcz: Since it's easy to produce a counter-example that has UB and will crash with common compilers, you can be absolutely sure that `reinterpret_cast` can't be used as an upcast. In general. The most common such example has `A` as a POD class and `B` introducing a virtual function, which can cause the compiler to introduce a vtable pointer at the start of the object.

Comment: cppreference updated with the appropriate pointer-interconvertible rule to add to derived-as-base lvalue access rule.. It could use some more polishing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what "safe" means, but the behavior of a program that uses this code is undefined. You can convert a pointer into an integer type that's large enough to hold the value, and you can convert that value back into a pointer **with the same type as the original**. The code in the question doesn't do that: it converts the value into a pointer **with a different type from the original**.

Comment: @Davidbrcz - undefined behavior means only that the language definition doesn't tell you what the code will do. It doesn't mean that bad things must happen, only that they might. Or they might not.

Answer (score -1):

In that particular case the code is safe. That's because the safety of *upcasting*. This is always allowed for public inheritance, *without an explicit type cast*.

In short you're just force something could be consider as implicit.

The passage of `B` type's address with a `uintptr_t` is useless also but allowed because "*the same type*".

## Edit

About [`uintptr_t`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/).

> Integer type capable of holding a value converted from a void pointer and then be converted back to that type with a value that compares equal to the original pointer.

Note "*compares equal to the original pointer*".

Comment: No, the cast does not just force something that would be implicit. It forces something that is not allowed by the rules. Depending on how inheritance is implemented, the implicit conversion could require an adjustment to the value of the pointer, and there's no way to do that when the cast goes directly to the base type.

Comment: @PeteBecker "*the implicit conversion could require an adjustment to the value of the pointer*", I didn't realize that, what do you mean? Can you make an example?

Comment: There is no requirement that the address of an object of a derived type be the same as the address of any of its bases. With every compiler that I know of, the address of an object is the same as the address of it's first base (i.e., its only base in single inheritance), but that's an implementation detail, not a requirement.